# Lookup Return Top Row

Tags: google-docs, lookup

I am trying to do a Lookup in Google Docs that returns the top row of where an item was found. I have attached an example image of my data. The data is in `F2:Q25` and I want to supply a number and have it return the corresponding team. For example, if I enter in `1`, I want it to return `Team1`. If I enter `79`, I want it to return `Team7` (the top row of where the result was found).

Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the principle of mathematical exclusion (find the smallest by adding an astronomical amount to everything that does not match) with the [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) and [MIN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MIN-function-735E28B8-829A-413A-BA38-668FCF0520D7) functions.

```
=index(A:Q, 1, min(index(column(F:Q)+($F$2:$Q$13<>C5)*1E+99, , )))
```

[image: 2D_matrix_lookup]