# Lookup in top row with selector from column

Tags: excel

I'm trying to do a "backwards" lookup.
Please see [JsFiddle here for show](https://jsfiddle.net/wu9qmzpc/6/) and where I have created a little table.

```
TopRow  1   2   3   4   5   6
A                       
B           T               
C               K           
D                       
E                       T   
F
```

With Vlookup-function I can easily look up what is on the table. But I need to get returned what is in `TopRow`. E.g. If I select `C` I will have `3` returned.

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

---

I am aware of this earlier question but it is numbers only:
[Lookup Return Top Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172155/lookup-return-top-row)

Comment: Does the value in the table not matter for this then (the `k` or the `t`)? Like... could that be an `X` or `hi mom` and the result would be the same?

Comment: Yes, it could be anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a datasetup like this:

[image]

In cell J2 and copied down is this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$G$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(INDEX($B$2:$G$7,MATCH(I2,$A$2:$A$7,0),0)<>"",),0)),"")
```

Comment: I prefer your answer as it avoids the array calculations of mine

Comment: This one was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table is in A1:G7 you could set your formula up as follows:

```
=INDEX(A1:G1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(B1:G1)/(INDEX(B2:G7,MATCH($I$2,$A$2:$A$7,0),0)<>""),1))
```

I placed the row name that was being looked up in I2

[image: POC]

Now you did not say what you wanted to happen if nothing was found, but you can wrap the whole thing in an IFERROR statement that will say "Not Found" or "All Blank"

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A1:G1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(B1:G1)/(INDEX(B2:G7,MATCH($I$2,$A$2:$A$7,0),0)<>""),1)),"All Blank")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Though I went on using Tigeravatars answer :)